# How to enable Role based user chat in Ejabberd

Tags: javascript, xmpp, ejabberd

How can I achieve role based chat system in web app.
Eg.
SuperAdmin can communicate with anyone in organisation.
Admin can communicate with Leads only.
Leads can communicate to Admin and their teams only.
Auditors can communicate to respective leads and their team users.
Users can communicate to respective auditors only.

Answer (score 1):

One idea that I guess nobody has tried before:

1. Use mod_shared_roster to define the different groups of users, and the teams.
2. Then define different **acl** **shared_group** for each group, see https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/configuration/#acl-definition
3. Install [mod_filter from ejabberd-contrib](https://github.com/processone/ejabberd-contrib/tree/master/mod_filter), and configure the different groups to only allow messaging the other groups acording to your design.

Disclaimer: I don't know if it's possible, and as I said, I doubt anybody did that before, because what I mentioned uses features recently available. If you try and finally get it working, it would be great if you add a comment here showing how you accomplished that great task. Good luck! :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid there is no an easy way to do it - there are no any ready XMPP XEPs for it. Everyone can send a message to everyone.

Probably you can just build this logic at your client-side app. E.g. to assign different tags (superadmin/admin/lead/) to your users and then decide, before chatting, what tag do both users have and can they communicate or not.

Regarding XMPP roles - there are only roles in a context of a group chat. https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0045.html . Users in a group chat have different roles/permissions.

Answer (score 0):

I do have a similar problem, which is that I'd like my users to be able to only talk to people in their respective rosters. So user A can only message user B, if both user A has user B, and user B has user A in his roster. Do you know whether it is possible to achieve that using mod_filter? (I'm fairly new to ejabberd)